# HttpClient Request like browser

Tags: c#, windows-8, http-headers

When I calling site www.livescore.com by HttpClient class I always getting error "500".
Probably server blocked request from HttpClients.

1)There is any other method to get html from webpage?

2)How I can set the headers to get html content?

When I set headers like in browser I always get stange encoded content.

```
    http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
    http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
    http_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
```

3) How I can slove this problem? Any suggestions?

I using Windows 8 Metro Style App in C# and HttpClientClass

Comment: What happens when you fetch this url with your browser ?

Comment: In browser page displaying correct. Have a look http://www.livescore.com/

Comment: Can you publish the whole function?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Here you go - note you have to decompress the gzip encoded-result you get back [as per](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15031419/3312) [mleroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470473/mleroy):

```
private static readonly HttpClient _HttpClient = new HttpClient();

private static async Task<string> GetResponse(string url)
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(url)))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

        using (var response = await _HttpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
            {
                return await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call such like:

```
var response = await GetResponse("http://www.livescore.com/").ConfigureAwait(false); // or var response = GetResponse("http://www.livescore.com/").Result;
```

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish the same effect without the "Accept-Encoding" header?

Answer (score 26):

Could try this as well to add compression support:

```
var compressclient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() 
{ 
AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip 
});
```

This adds the headers too.

According to the same thread support is now in Windows Store framework: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/429bb65c-5f6b-42e0-840b-1f1ea3626a42/httpclient-data-compression-and-caching?prof=required

Answer (score 5):

Several things to take note of.

1. That site requires you to provide a user agent, or it returns a 500 HTTP error.
2. A GET request to livescore.com responds with a 302 to livescore.us. You need to handle the redirection or directly request livescore.us
3. You need to decompress a gzip-compressed response

This code works using the .NET 4 Client Profile, I'll let you figure out if it fits a Windows Store app.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.livescore.com");
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17";

string content;

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(response.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
{
    content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: OP is not using `HttpWebRequest`, but rather `HttpClient`. But you're spot-on about points 1 and 3.

Comment: You're right; well the OP didn't seem set on using HttpClient (see his first question) so hopefully it'll still be useful :)

Comment: Thanks! Is good answer but in Winodws 8 only HttpClient is supported.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can be pretty certain that they have done everything to stop developers from screen-scraping.

If I try from a standard C# project using this code :

```
  var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.livescore.com ");
  var response = request.GetResponse();
```

I get this response:

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Comment: Yes I know :) But we are developers and we need to slove problems like this :)

Comment: There are paid services out there.
This is illegal hacking. Maybe you should find another site.

Comment: Illegal? Why? When You call this site by browser is illegall too?

Comment: Livescores is big business, most sites have syndication deals or xml feeds that you can pay for.

Comment: Duplicating someone elses data without their permission is often deemed illegal though most sites also cover this in their Terms of service or a usage policy of which I can't find neither on livescore.com. I would still suggest that you contact the site and ask for permission for your project and if they have any APIs/feeds of their own you can use.