# HttpClient GetAsync Method 403 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpclient, http-status-code-403

I am trying a simple display of github repositories.   The url "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=pluralsight" works in my browser return json and works in fiddler but the following in my .NET Web App is getting a 403 Forbidden error.  Can anyone help me understand a fix?  My controller is as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    public ActionResult Index()
        {
        Tweets model = null;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var task = client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=pluralsight")
            .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
            {
                var response = taskwithresponse.Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var readtask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Tweets>();
                readtask.Wait();
                model = readtask.Result;

            });
        task.Wait();
        return View(model.results);
        }
    }
```

I have a class defined as follows (ignore that it is called Tweets) originally was trying to access twitter api.

```
namespace HttpClientMVCDemo.Controllers
{
public class Tweets
    {
    public Tweet[] results;
    }
public class Tweet
    {
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code view auto generated based on Amit's classes below:

```
@model IEnumerable<HttpClientMVCDemo.Controllers.Gits>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.total_count)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.incomplete_results)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.total_count)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.incomplete_results)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new       { /*id=item.PrimaryKey*/ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well here are some modification in your model class

First Json string contain array of **items** not **results**

and you forget to provide get and set propertyin model class.

So This is new modified model class.

```
public class Tweets
    {
        public int total_count { get; set; }
        public bool incomplete_results { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
    }
```

And to get data from that url, You need to add `User-Agent` header in request.
And also add this in your web.cofig file

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

So here is complete code.

```
Tweets model = null;           
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required");
            var task = client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=pluralsight")
                .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
                {
                    var response = taskwithresponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    response.Wait();
                    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweets>(response.Result);
                });
            task.Wait();
            return View(model.items);
```

And in your view should accept this type of model

```
@model IEnumerable<HttpClientMVCDemo.Controllers.Item>
```

Comment: Amit, I tried your solution.  I had already taken care of the system.net addition.  I remodeled my class and added the code you list.  Now I am getting a different error  "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HttpClientMVCDemo.Controllers.Item]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[HttpClientMVCDemo.Controllers.Gits]'."

Comment: I am having trouble fitting it into comments (too long).

Comment: @jaykum: replace this line `@model IEnumerable<HttpClientMVCDemo.Controllers.Gits>` with `@model IEnumerable<HttpClientMVCDemo.Controllers.Item>`

Comment: Okay that worked, having some issues with model in the for each loop, I will try to fix it and if I can't I will post again later (have to go to work).  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Amit, sorry, work took me away.  I really appreciate your help.  I had to rebuild the View since I changed it from Gits to Item and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser automatically adds several accept headers to the request. You might have to add the headers in your request to avoid the 403.

```
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/json");
```

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441688/im-getting-403-with-httpclient-on-portable-class-library). The easiest way is to use Fiddler to check your request.

Furthermore you should not call `Wait` on your async call. Better declare the action as `async` and call `await client.GetAsync();`Otherwise you might get a deadlock. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock).

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 403: Forbidden is thrown because of administrative rules from github site.

Accessing api(https://api.github.com/) from github site expects 'User-Agent' header.

This can be resolved using below code:

```
HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();    
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required");
var res = Client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=pluralsight").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Refernce:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#user-agent-required