# How to fix Unable to send GET request - 403 error

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

I am new to the C# world, and can't for the life of me figure out how to get around this error. I am trying to make a simple get request using a platform API key. I have built out the API connection in Google App Script on the same laptop, and it works fine, but when trying to build out the same API in C#, it is returning:

```json
{StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Sun, 13 Mar 2022 02:41:29 GMT
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: close
  CF-Chl-Bypass: 1
  Permissions-Policy: accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()
  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
  Server: cloudflare
  CF-RAY: 6eb1692f8bd776c3-LHR
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
}}
```

The API documentation says:

> "To authenticate against the API, include your API key in the 'Authorization' header, prefixed with 'Key ', in every request. Example: 'Authorization: Key yourapikey'"

And so, I have tried adding this to 
a) the HttpClient via `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization`
b) the HttpClient via `HttpClient.DefaultHeaders.Add`
c) the HttpRequestMessage via `HttpRequestMessage.Headers.Add` 
In each instance, the request URI looks good, as well as the headers, but still returning `403`.
My current structure is:

```cs
// services
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("myplatform", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://seller-api.myplatform.com/v2/");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
});

// controller
// constructor uses IHttpClientFactory
this._httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("myplatform");

// service
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Key", platformKey);

string endPoint = "offers" + CreateQueryString(pageNumber, pageSize);
// example endPoint: offers?page_number=1&page_size=100

var requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
     Method = HttpMethod.Get,
     RequestUri = new Uri(httpClient.BaseAddress + endPoint)
};

try
{    
     var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMsg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
                    
}
```

Again, the content of the call works when calling through GoogleAppScript. What am I doing wrong in C#, and how can I correct this?

Not sure if this is all the information needed - let me know otherwise! Important to note, the target framework is `.NET 6.0`.

**EDIT**

As suggested by a comment around duplicate clients, I have removed the client factory. I am now creating a new `HttpClient` in the controller constructor, and passing this client to my service to do the GET request.

```cs
this._httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

Again, the client and the request message look well formed at time of request but still returning `403 error`. Is there an issue with my VS22 client, or web client etc.?

Also, the call I am making successfully via Google AppScript is using `UrlFetchApp`. Not sure what is the issue here with the C# side..

**EDIT2**

Adding current GAS code for reference:

```js
var url = 'https://seller-api.platform.com/v2';
var end_point = '/offers?';
var header = {
    'Authorization': api_key
  }
var params = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': header
  }

// call API
var page_query = 'page_number=' + page + '&page_size=' + maxItemsPerPage;
var full_url = url + end_point + page_query;

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(full_url, params);
```

Comment: it looks like you are using multiple http clients. please try to detangle that.

Comment: @DanielA.White if I set `_httpClient = new HttpClient()` in my controller constructor, and set the `.BaseAddress` and `.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add` in the controller method, I get the same `403 Forbidden` response.

Comment: it still looks like you are using multiple ones - even thru the client factory. its really hard to follow.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am not sure I follow. I remove the client factory and create a new client in my controller constructor... That then gets passed to my service method... Where should the client be defined?

Comment: Use [Filddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic) to examine your HTTP request and compare it with the working one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP [403 Forbidden response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

There are two ways add request headers when using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0):

- Add headers for all requests using `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`.

```cs
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Key", platformKey);
        var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(GetRandomNumberUrl);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

- Add headers per request using `HttpRequestMessage.Headers`.

```cs
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, randomNumberUrl))
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", platformKey);
            var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

Your problem is here in this line:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Key", platformKey);
```

your `_httpClient`  and Authorization httpClient is not same instance.

Try this way:

```
                HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
                string url = "https://seller-api.platform.com/v2";
                string end_point = "/offers?";
                string api_key = "key here";
                string page_query = "page_number=" + 10 + "&page_size=" + 20;
                string full_url = url + end_point + page_query;

                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
                {
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", api_key);
                    var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);

                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var m = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
```

[image]

Solution 2:
Try calling it [like a browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.tryaddwithoutvalidation?view=net-6.0) :

```
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                string url = "https://gatewayt.whatever.com/chkt/request/request.php";
                string end_point = "/offers?";
               string  api_key = "key here";
                string page_query = "page_number=" + 10 + "&page_size=" + 20;
                string full_url = url + end_point + page_query;

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Key", api_key);

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

source: [Request like browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026953/httpclient-request-like-browser) [Link1](https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-add-request-headers-when-using-httpclient/) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801195/adding-headers-when-using-httpclient-getasync) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685063/httpclient-getasync-method-403-error)

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this and still getting `403`. I have also tried to only introduce the `HttpClient` in my service class to ensure there is only one client being used, and still returning `403`. I have triple checked the API key being used and still `403`. Again, the client query is well formed before the call and looks identical to the call being made from GAS. What else could be causing the issue?

Comment: could you please share your working code of  ```GoogleAppScript```??

Comment: I have added in `EDIT2`

Comment: I am not sure how `UrlFetchApp` deserialises the `params` that are passed - I tried to find this but couldn't find any resource for this as I was hoping it would give me more information around how to adjust my C# call.

Comment: @Dean Answer is edited please check.....

Comment: Unfortunately, the request is well formed, i.e. the key is in the Authorization header when being sent - it is still returning `403` with that...

Comment: @Dean please try [Solution 2], this must be help you to solve this issue..