# Send Asp.net HttpClient Get result to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc controller method "Index" as showed below. I want to use HttpClient GetAsync method to get a response from wwww.google.com and then send this response as the response to browser, so browser shows www.google.com. But I do not know how to replace response with the response I got from client.GetAsync. Please help! I don't want to use redirect though.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var httpMessage = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");


        return ???;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the response from the http call as a string using the `ReadAsStringAsync()` method and return that string back as the response from your action method.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var httpMessage = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

    var r = await httpMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Content(r);
}
```

The above code will return you the content of *google.com* when you access the `Index` action.

Answer (score 1):

please try to see this post [HttpClient Request like browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026953/httpclient-request-like-browser)

```
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    using (var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
    {
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

I make sample on my machine

full action here

```
    public async Task<string> Index()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");


        var httpMessage = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

        httpMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        using (var responseStream = await httpMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        // return View();
    }
```

[example for get cookie from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318102/struggling-trying-to-get-cookie-out-of-response-with-httpclient-in-net-4-5?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: Wow, I have google run in my local machine now, look I edit my code

Comment: Hi Abdelrhman, I want the browser has the same google session as the server got from google. In your example, does the browser has the same session, or it simply display the page? So, if google.com sent me a cookie, I want that cookie also be sent to the browser.

Comment: I found this example for cookie display,  I will update the post also