# Not able to download file using C# from a web api which works using postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have recently started working with web api's.

I need to download a file in C# project from a web api, which works fine when I hit the web api using postman's send and download option. Refer to the image, also please check the response in header's tab. This way, I am able to directly download the file to my computer.

[image: Api call using postman]

I want to do the same from my C# project, I found following two links which shows how to download a file from web api.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HttpClient-Downloading-to-4cc138fd
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/16/downloading-a-google-map-to-local-file.aspx

I am using the following code in C# project to get the response:

```
 private static async Task FileDownloadAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html");
            try
            {
                // _address is exactly same which I use from postman
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_address);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

However I am not getting the response at all (before I can start to convert the response to a file), please check the error message coming:

[image: Error message]

What am I missing here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the (500s) error says - it's the Server that rejects the request. The only thing I see that could cause an issues is the charset encoding. Yours is the default UTF-8. You could try with other encodings.

Comment: See my updated answer. You use the default encoding, but the Server may require something different...like utf-16. Can you find somedocs for this service?

Comment: I am pretty much new to web api's , if you know, could you please let me know how can I specify encoding while making an httpClient call

Comment: You can specify this in the headers. Here are some [code examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026953/httpclient-request-like-browser) which are very close to your case.

Answer (score 1):

Below method uses:

1. SSL certificate (comment out code for cert, if you don't use it)
2. Custom api header for additional layer of security (comment out Custom_Header_If_You_Need code, if you don't need that)
3. EnsureSuccessStatusCode will throw an error, when response is not 200.  This error will be caught in  and converted to a human readable string format to show on your screen (if you need to).  Again, comment it out if you don't need that.

   ```
   private byte[] DownloadMediaMethod(string mediaId)
   {
       var cert = new X509Certificate2("Keystore/p12_keystore.p12", "p12_keystore_password");
       var handler = new WebRequestHandler { ClientCertificates = { cert } };
       using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
       {
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Custom_Header_If_You_Need", "Value_For_Custom_Header");
           var httpResponse = client.GetAsync(new Uri($"https://my_api.my_company.com/api/v1/my_media_controller/{mediaId}")).Result;
           //Below one line is most relevant to this question, and will address your problem.  Other code in this example if just to show the solution as a whole.
           var result = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
           try
           {
               httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               if (result == null || result.Length == 0) throw;
               using (var ms = new MemoryStream(result))
               {
                   var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                   throw new Exception(sr.ReadToEnd(), ex);
               }
           }
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```

Once you have your http response 200, you can use the received bytes[] as under to save them in a file:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request header says that you accept HTML responses only. That could be a problem.

Comment: Leave out the content type altogether.